# How to set loading indicator for Angular route params pipe*

Tags: angular, rxjs

I am using angular and rxjs. My problem is showing a loading indicator

```
  isLoading: BehaviorSubject<boolean> = new BehaviorSubject(false);

  ngOnInit() {
    this.items = this.route.paramMap.pipe(
      tap(() => this.isLoading.next(true)),
      switchMap((params: ParamMap) => this.myservice.getItems(params.get("id"))),
      tap(() => this.isLoading.next(false))
    )
  }
```

Html is:

```
 <i class="spinner" *ngIf="(isLoading | async)"></i>
 <div *ngIf="!(isLoading | async)">
    <grid *ngFor="let item of items | async;" [item]="item">
      ...
    </grid>
 </div>
```

But this code throws an exception.

> ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed
>   after it was checked. Previous value: 'ngIf: [object Object]'. Current
>   value: 'ngIf: true'.

Comment: how do you subscribe to `this.items`? do you pass items as input to some child component and then subscribe to it from inside?

Comment: I updated the html in the post, I am using item as async.

Comment: @barteloma Try to set the `changeDetection` to `OnPush`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend not using the `async` pipe unless you have a firm grasp on Observable streams. Don't be afraid to simplify and replace the fancy operators and techniques with simpler ones.

component.ts

```
 isLoading: boolean = false;
 ngOnInit() {
    this.isLoading = true;

    this.route.paramMap.pipe(
        switchMap((params: ParamMap) => this.myservice.getItems(params.get("id"))),
    ).subscribe((result: any) => {
        this.items = result;
        this.isLoading = false;
    }, ((error: any) => this.isLoading = false));
  }
```

component.html:

It looks like you are trying to make a grid instance for each item?
If so, `Item` (singular) is a weird name here.

```
<i class="spinner" *ngIf="isLoading"></i>
<div *ngIf="!isLoading">
    <ng-container *ngFor="let item of items">
        <grid [item]="item">
          ...
        </grid>
    </ng-container>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this other approach in order to get what you want to do. I use delay and of in items$ simulating an HTTP request or async code.

```js
  import { BehaviorSubject, of, Observable } from 'rxjs';
  import { delay, finalize, first } from 'rxjs/operators';

  items$: Observable<number[]> = of([1,2,3]).pipe(
    delay(2000),
    finalize(() => {
      this.isLoadingSubject.next(false)
    })
  );

  isLoadingSubject: BehaviorSubject<boolean> = new BehaviorSubject(true);

  isLoading$: Observable<boolean> = this.isLoadingSubject.asObservable();

  ngOnInit() {
    // first operator unsubscribe automatically
    this.items$.pipe(first()).subscribe();
  }
```

```html
<div *ngIf="(isLoading$ | async); else itemsTemplate">
  Loading...
</div>
<ng-template #itemsTemplate>  
  <p>Items template</p>
  <div *ngFor="let item of items$ | async;">
   {{ item }}
  </div>
</ng-template>
```